# Sum of two numbers

Tags: java, sum

I want to make sum of two numbers. But I have problems to do that. I don't understand why my sum is always zero.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Numbers {
    static int a;
    static int b;
    static int result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the first number:");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("Type the second number:");
        String b = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(b);
        display();
    }

    public static void display(){
        result=a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off taking input as an int and storing them directly in your int variables as opposed to strings. You could also parse the strings into ints but it's an unnecessary step if you have dependable input.

Comment: In any case Gordon's answer is correct; you're dealing with variables of different scopes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a java programmer, but I can see that you have global variables called `a` and `b` and local variables called `a` and `b`.

Your `main()` is setting the local variables.  `display()` is reading the global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need static "global" variables in your case. So you can remove this piece of code :

```
static int a;
static int b;
static int result;
```

Then, juste use your local variables and give a and b as parameter to `display()` method like this :

```
public static void display(int a, int b){
  System.out.println("Sum of numbers is " + (a+b));
}
```

Eventually, you will need to cast `String`s obtained via `in.nextLine()` and cast them to int, with `Integer.parseInt()` for example. Or just directly get integer from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You did couple of mistakes :

1. String a and String b is a local variable to main() method. So you cant access
   those variables from display() method. `result=a+b;`in display() method is actually adding a and b which are declared in the class level whose by default value is 0. so summation is 0.
2. Even if you write `result=a+b;`inside main method it will not work. Because a and b are String in main method and you cant do addition on String

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass {
     static int a;
     static  int b;
     static int result;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the first number:");
          a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("Type the second number:");
        b = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(b);
        display();
    }
    public static void display(){
        result=(a+b);
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers is " + result);
    }
}
```

Use nextInt in place of nextLine method .If the type is int then use nextInt method.

Answer (score 0):

There's few things that's going wrong.

You have 2 global variable

```
static int a;
static int b;
```

Which you want to capture from input.
But instead you're storing it to a local variable here inside the Main.

```
String a = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println("Type the second number:");
String b = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(b);
```

Also keep in mind you're capturing them as String.

Then in the *display()* method you're print the sum of the Global Variable which were never initialised and hold the default integer value 0.

So to fix your code you should have something like this

```
import java.util.*;
public class Numbers {
 static int a;
 static int b;
 static int result;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type the first number:");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println("Type the second number:");
    b = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(b);
    display();
 }

 public static void display(){
    result=a+b;
    System.out.println("Sum of numbers is " + result);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        int y=sc.nextInt();
    
        System.out.println(x+y);

    }
}
```

Comment: that's now what the Author is facing. it's not only adding two variable, it's about the mistake in a way using code to calculate